# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I made an activity with a viewPager, and well, it crashes as soon as the `viewPager.setAdapter` works. Here's the crash log.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 26488162 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 24MB until OOM
                  at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:629)
                  at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:723)
                  at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:100)
                  at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:345)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Here's the activity's class

```
public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
        ViewPager setupPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.setupViewpager); 
        SetupPagerAdapter setupPagerAdapter = new SetupPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());    
        setupPager.setAdapter(setupPagerAdapter);
   }
}
```

Here's the `SetupPagerAdapter`

```
public class SetupPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SetupPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return new SetupFragmentOne().newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and Here's `SetupFragmentOne`

```
public class SetupFragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public SetupFragmentOne newInstance() {
        SetupFragmentOne fragment = new SetupFragmentOne();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment_1, container);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"coolvetica_rg.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setupText1);
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to figure out why your app uses so much memory. Do you have a lot of large images? Do you have a memory leak somewhere? These are the kinds of things you need to track down and then fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this in your manifest file:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

This error occurs when Java Virtual Machine (JVM) cannot allocate a object due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.

try changing this line:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment_1, container);
```

to

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment_1, container,false);
```

To resolve out of memory error...better approach :

If you are using lots of bitmaps or drawable images...you should put different resolution images in different folders...hdpi,xhdpi etc...
see this :https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Also unbind your drawables when activity destroyed..so that  memory can be freed by Garbage collector

```
 private void unbindDrawables(View view)
{
        if (view.getBackground() != null)
        {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
}
```

Also see this: https://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/solution-for-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/

Comment: now it gives me `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size`

Comment: the better approach to overcome this issue do not use large size images in your application or put the images in right selected folder according to the drawable folders in android.

Comment: largeHeap is a hack that will negatively impact every other app on the phone.  The correct solution is to figure out why you're using so much memory and fix that.  Suggesting using largeHeap without a VERY good reason is wrong and unprofessional.

Comment: i have edited the answer,,,hope now it is professional

Comment: this effectivelly kills the point of the view cache.